# How to allow pdf files in .htaccess?

Tags: linux, php, htaccess

I have this following codes in my htaccess file, but it doesn't allow pdf file to open, it will redirect to 404 page. how can I allow pdf files to open based on my following htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt\.pdf)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|pdf|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I highly appreciate your help. Thank

Comment: uhh `robots\.txt\.pdf` matches exactly "robots.txt.pdf" which is an unusual file to look for. are you sure you don't want a `|` like between all those others?

Comment: RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|updates|asset|mob|robots\.txt|\.pdf)    but still it's same. you mean like this ?

Comment: This one also doesn't work: RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|public|assets|uploads|themes|updates|asset|mob|robots\.pdf)

Comment: Please guide me how to allow all pdf files?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `RewriteCond` does not match `*.pdf` files at all.
Try to add the following pattern in your `RewriteCond`.

```
|(.+)\.pdf
```

Have a look at references, I put below. 
More or less, form of `RewriteCond` depends on `Apache` version you do use on your server. References present quite good written examples.

For security reasons (depending on application you want to serve and it's logic), I would add few more conditions before rewrite. Verifying if your file exists and is not a directory. But, as I said, everything depends on application logic.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

References:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html

Comment: I'm using PHP codeigniter, I have access to all images files in uploads folder, but I don't have access to PDF file, it will redirect to 404 page. I've search everything inside the codes, I got confused, I don't know how to get access PDF file inside uploads folder. If you know, I highly appreciate if you share your knowledge. thanks in advance.